# Remove duplicates from PySpark array column by checking each element

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates

I have a Spark dataframe that contains 2 array columns:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|                                                  var1|             var2|
+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|       [black tea, green tea, tea, yerba mate, oolong]|      [green tea]|
|[milk, toned milk, standardised milk, full cream milk]| [cow or buffalo]|
+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I need to remove duplicates according to the following rules:

1. Check each element of the column `var1` with the value of `var2` column and remove words from the `var1` that **partially** (for example, 1 word - `tea`) or **completely** (for example, 2 words - `green tea`) match the `var2` value.
2. If there is a complete match and the element is removed completely from the `var1` column, then the extra comma (inside the array or at the end) must also be removed
3. Also remove repeating words from elements in the `var1` column.
   For example, if one element contains a word that is then repeated in other elements, these duplicates should be removed (for example, we have a `milk`, then `toned milk`, `standardized milk`, `full cream milk` - in this case, the desired output looks like this: `milk, toned, standardised, full cream`)

Required output:

```
+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
|                                   var1|             var2|
+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
|            [black, yerba mate, oolong]|      [green tea]|
|[milk, toned, standardised, full cream]| [cow or buffalo]|
+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using arrays higher order functions:

1. Flatten array `var2` into array of single words then using `transform` on array `var1` remove each word that corresponds to on of the words in array `var2`. finally filter the empty string elements.
2. Join array `var1`, and remove duplicate words using regex, then split again to get array

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "regex",
    F.concat_ws("|", F.flatten(F.transform("var2", lambda x: F.split(x, "\\s+"))))
).withColumn(
    "var1",
    F.filter(F.expr("transform(var1, x -> regexp_replace(x, regex, ''))"), lambda x: F.trim(x) != "")
).withColumn(
    "var1",
    F.regexp_replace(F.array_join(F.reverse("var1"), "#"), r"\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)", "")
).withColumn(
    "var1",
    F.transform(F.reverse(F.split("var1", "#")), lambda x: F.trim(x))
).drop("regex")
```

Using this example df:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (["black tea", "green tea", "tea", "yerba mate", "oolong"], ["green tea"]),
    (["milk", "toned milk", "standardised milk", "full cream milk"], ["cow or buffalo"])
], ["var1", "var2"])
```

You get

```
df1.show(truncate=False)
# +---------------------------------------+----------------+
# |var1                                   |var2            |
# +---------------------------------------+----------------+
# |[black, yerba mate, oolong]            |[green tea]     |
# |[milk, toned, standardised, full cream]|[cow or buffalo]|
# +---------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a savanna buffalo not cow :-))

```
df = (
  #Split var1 and var2 into single words contained in a list and store in temp columns
  df.select('*',*[split(regexp_replace(col(x).cast('string'),'\]|\[|\,',''),'\s').alias(f'{x}_1') for x in df.columns])
     #Leverage the rich array functions to remove words that exists in var2 from var1
      
     .withColumn('var1', array_except('var1','var2_1'))
     .withColumn('var1', array_except('var1','var2'))
).select('var1','var2')


df.show(truncate=False)


df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|var1                                                  |var2            |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|[black, yerba mate, oolong]                           |[green tea]     |
|[milk, toned milk, standardised milk, full cream milk]|[cow or buffalo]|
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!:)) This is very close to the desired output, but is it possible to preserve composite items such as `yerba mate` and `full cream` here (I mean, do not separate them with a comma, as in many cases some meaning will be lost)?

Comment: See my edit, just except twice

Comment: Sorry, but after the last edits, my input column `var1` does not transform at all (I have `[black tea,  green tea,  tea,  white tea,  yerba mate,  oolong]`). That is, I can't get the output you got, although getting such an output would be perfect

Comment: let me look into that